# Android button question

Tags: android, button

i am trying to create an app. When user clicks on the button, it gets pressed (image is loaded). When he clicks the button now, it gets unpressed (image is loaded) and so on. I am using the code below with which the problem is that when i click on the unpressed button 3rd time it doesn't get into the pressed state again. So at first click it gets pressed, at second click it gets unpressed, and at the 3rd click nothing happens.

```
 NameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        NameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                NameButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
                NameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
                {
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        NameButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unpressed);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might do it like that:

```
    NameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    NameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (setPressed)
                NameButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
            else
                NameButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unpressed);
            setPressed = !setPressed;
        }
    });
```

And have a boolean variable setPressed as a member variable.

Alternatively, consider using [ToggleButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html).

Answer (score 1):

Whoa... that's rather unnecessary...

Have a look at the ImageButton documentation page at the top on how to use a selector to define a different image for different states.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html

Then in your layout's xml, you'd use

```
android:background="@drawable/selectorfilename.xml"
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTag()` and `getTag()` methods to get tag of button. Depending on the tag set your background of button. in xml also use `android:tag`

### in XML

```
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/openpdfbutton"
   android:layout_width="100dip"
  android:layout_height="60dip"
  android:text="Click"
  android:background="@drawable/cancelfocus"
  android:tag="@drawable/cancelfocus"
  />
```

### in OnClick Listener

```
NameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        NameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

if(NameButton.getTag().equals(R.drawable.cancelfocus)){

    NameButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cancel_unfocus);
    NameButton.setTag(R.drawable.cancel_unfocus);
    }else{
        System.out.println("...UnFocus Button clicked...");
        NameButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cancelfocus);
        NameButton.setTag(R.drawable.cancelfocus);
    }

        }
    });
```

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

fist you have to chacke the wether that button is perssed or not..
if that button is pressed then you do that events and if not then else part ..
so for that ur code something like this:--

NameButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    NameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            if (setPressed)
                NameButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
            else
                NameButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.unpressed);
            setPressed = !setPressed;
        }
    });